# How to write security rule for firestore with "A map of values" query?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Using the "A map of values" query method documented in https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays

If I have this:

```
db.collection('posts')
  .where(`editorUids.${currentUser.uid}`, '==', true)
```

How would the security rule look like for restricting `posts` collection to only allow `list` if `editorUids.x == true`, where `x` is `request.auth.uid`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
match /posts/{post} {
  allow list: if resource.data[request.auth.uid] == true;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.